# Getting Serial data in linux kernel module programming

Tags: linux, module, serial-port, kernel

I am wanted to write a module which should read/write into a Virtual serial port created by a USB serial driver viz /dev/ttyUSB0. How to achieve this? please provide some pointers.

Comment: The kernel already supports serial ports. What exactly do you want more? Why can't your needs be achieved in user space?

Comment: Reading / writing data to the serial port should be done in userspace. However, if you want to hijack (ie spy or inject data for example into an existing driver), then you should provide more details on what exactly you need to achieve.

Comment: I have a serial modem providing digital pcm voice data via /dev/ttyUSB0. Needed to write an alsa  driver to register/expose this interface  as a  soundcard. so that audio routing becomes easy.

Comment: @shodanex  @ basilestarynkevitch Additional info : i find this driver has a similar functionality <linux_source_home>/sound/drvers/serial-u16550.c which uses ioport address and irq no. as arguments. I tried to find the irq and ioport address for /dev/ttyUSB0 by setserial -a /dev/ttyUSB0. this fails with Cannot get serial info: Invalid argument.